# How to setup the clock.py file to schedule scrapy spiders crawling deployed on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, scrapy, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I've deployed my [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) spiders on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) and they are running well but I have to launch them manually via the command line tool.

I would like to automate this process with a [custom clock process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes) but I'm struggling to write the clock.py file that would trigger the whole scraping.

I would like my spiders to start crawling at the same time (once a day). From the [scrapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-from-script) I found two strategies that could work for me:

- Run multiple spiders simultaneously with the `CrawlProcess()` or the `CrawlerRunner()`
- Run the spiders sequentially with the `CrawlerRunner()`

I have honestly no idea which one to use so I'll give it a try to run them sequentially.

This is what I have in my clock.py file:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

from apscheduler.schedulers.twisted import TwistedScheduler
import pytz

from bike_price.spiders.a4en1 import A4en1Spider
from bike_price.spiders.lepoledeloccasion import LepoledeloccasionSpider


configure_logging()
runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(A4en1Spider)
    yield runner.crawl(LepoledeloccasionSpider)
    reactor.stop()
```

This is running perfectly:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    crawl()
    reactor.run()
```

But when I'm trying to implement the apscheduler like below then it's not working as expected:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = TwistedScheduler(timezone=pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris'))
    scheduler.add_job(crawl, trigger='cron', hour='17', minute='49')
    scheduler.start()
    reactor.run()
```

It seems like I'm scraping nothing:

```
...
2021-11-04 17:49:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-11-04 17:49:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-11-04 17:49:00 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-11-04 17:49:00 [apscheduler.executors.default] INFO: Job "crawl (trigger: cron[hour='17', minute='49'], next run at: 2021-11-05 17:49:00 CET)" executed successfully
```

Any ideas or explanations?

Thanks!